# Bootstrap on change textarea not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get the name and value of my Bootstrap Vue textarea on change, it doesn't seem to be firing. My textarea is as follows:

```
<b-form-textarea v-if="input.type === 'textarea' && !input.editor"
                        v-bind:id="input.name"
                        v-bind:name="input.name"
                        v-model="input.value"
                        v-on:change="edit(input.name, input.value)"
                        :rows="3">
                      </b-form-textarea>
```

my function **edit()** is:

```
edit (name, value) {
      this.editedFields.push({name, value});
    }
```

This works for inputs such as normal input fields, but doesn't seem to fire the function for a textarea

Comment: Any codepen / jsfiddle template to test?

Comment: Try using input method on this.

Comment: @Riddhi input method? Does this mean changing my field to a generic <input> with a type of textarea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No use @input method.

```
<b-form-textarea v-if="input.type === 'textarea' && !input.editor"
                        v-bind:id="input.name"
                        v-bind:name="input.name"
                        v-model="input.value"
                        @input="edit(input.name, input.value)"
                        :rows="3">
                      </b-form-textarea>
```

Comment: This works, thanks, I'm using `this.editedFields.push({name, value});` to add to my `editedFields` array, every time I edit the field it adds a new set to the array. how could I add a check to see if a name exists as per my function and just update the value if this makes sense rather than appending more?

Comment: why don't you directly assign value in this.editedFields through  input.value as you have already used v-model.

Comment: Because this input is inside a `v-for` amongst other inputs and input types with are fetched dynamically from a server thus there could be any number of inputs and input types. That's why I'm checking the input type etc, the inputs are part of a form.

Comment: How about setting your this.editedFields as an object with name as key and setting value.So even if it will repeat you can check if it exists as a key.If you cannot make it as object do let me know the structure of your this.editedFields.

Comment: I'm struggling to grasp how to do that? This is the part I need to edit? `this.editedFields.push({name, value});` ? What would I need to change potentially, btw, `editedFields` is an empty array: `[]` within my data, and is automatically populated with content based on the edit function that gets the value of a field on change and adds it to the array.

Comment: Declare this.editFields = {} and then this.$set(this.editFields,name,value).You may try this.It will create your editFields as name:value pairs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187874/discussion-between-ryan-holton-and-riddhi).